# Why is this behavior allowed in the Java Memory Model?

Tags: java, concurrency, compiler-optimization, java-memory-model, causality

Causality in JMM seems to be the most confusing part of it. I have a few questions regarding JMM causality, and allowed behaviors in concurrent programs.

As I understand, the current JMM always prohibits causality loops. (Am I right?)

Now, as per the [JSR-133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf) document, page 24, Fig.16, we have an example where:

Initially `x = y = 0`

**Thread 1:**

```
r3 = x;
if (r3 == 0)
    x = 42;
r1 = x;
y = r1;
```

**Thread 2:**

```
r2 = y;
x = r2;
```

Intuitively, `r1 = r2 = r3 = 42` seems impossible. However, it is not only mentioned as possible, but also 'allowed' in JMM.

For the possibility, the explanation from the document which I fail to understand is:

> A compiler could determine that the only values ever assigned to `x` are
>   0 and 42. From that, the compiler could deduce that, at the point
>   where we execute `r1 = x`, either we had just performed a write of 42 to
>   `x`, or we had just read `x` and seen the value 42. In either case, it
>   would be legal for a read of `x` to see the value 
>   42. It could then change `r1 = x` to `r1 = 42`; this would allow `y = r1` to be transformed  to `y = 42` and performed earlier, resulting in the
>   behavior in question. In this  case, the write to `y` is committed
>   first.

My question is, what kind of compiler optimization is it really? (I am compiler-ignorant.) Since 42 is written only conditionally, when the `if` statement is satisfied, how can the compiler decide to go with the writing of `x`?

Secondly, even if compiler does this speculative optimization, and commits `y = 42` and
then finally makes `r3 = 42` , isn't it a violation of causality loop, since there is no cause and effect distinction left now?

In fact there is one example in the same document (page 15, Figure 7) where a similar causal loop is mentioned as unacceptable.

So how come this execution order is legal in JMM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained, the only values ever written to `x` are 0 and 42. Thread 1:

```
r3 = x; // here we read either 0 or 42
if (r3 == 0)
  x = 42;  
// at this point x is definitely 42
r1 = x;
```

Therefore the JIT compiler can rewrite `r1 = x` as `r1 = 42`, and further `y = 42`. The point is, Thread 1 will **always, unconditionally** write 42 to `y`. The `r3` variable is in fact redundant and could be completely eliminated from the machine code. So the code in the example only gives the appearance of a causal arrow from `x` to `y`, but detailed analysis shows that there is in fact no causality. The surprising consequence is that the write to `y` can be committed early.

A general note on optimization: I take it you are familiar with performance penalties involved in reading from the main memory. That is why the JIT compiler is bent on refusing to do it whenever possible, and in this example it turns out that it doesn't in fact need to read `x` in order to know what to write to `y`.

A general note on notation: `r1`, `r2`, `r3` are **local variables** (they could be on the stack or in CPU registers); `x`, `y` are **shared variables** (these are in the main memory). Without taking this into account, the examples will not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler can perform some analyses and optimizations and end with following code for Thread1:

```
y=42; // step 1
r3=x; // step 2
x=42; // step 3
```

For single-threaded execution, this code is equivalent to the original code and so is legal. Then, if the code of Thread2 is executed between step 1 and step2 (which is well possible), then r3 is assigned 42 also.

The whole idea of this code sample is to demonstrate the need of proper synchronization.

Comment: @Alexei That explains some of it. But, shouldn't the compiler make it `r3 = 0` instead of `r3 = 42` ? Or they are just showing 'a possibility'!

Comment: Compiler does not make `r3=42`, it just leaves `r3=x` intact. Compiler optimization are not always performed to the maximum depth. If there is minimal possibility that optimization can violate correctness, it is abandoned. In the given code, there is no such circumstances, but they can appear if some other code is present. Besides, compiler can decide that `r3=0` is of the same price as `r3=x`.

Answer (score 1):

Its is worth nothing that the `javac` doesn't optimise the code to a significant degree.  The JIT optimises the code but is fairly conservative about re-ordering code.  The CPU can re-order execution and it does this to small degree quite allot.

Forcing the CPU to not do instruction level optimisation is fairly expensive e.g. it can slow it down by a factor of 10 or more.  AFAIK, the Java designers wanted to specify the minimum of guarantees needed which would work efficiently on most CPUs.